# Unity Collider doesn't work for box and circle collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-container

I created two game object.

One is box and the other one is a ball. Then I added collider  them( box collider and circle collider) to collision them. But it's not working. When I hit play button, the ball just falling to eternity ^^.
I searched on the internet and looked for possible solutions and they didn't work.

*Is trigger unchecked.
*Attached rigidbody2d to the ball.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BoxCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BoxCollider.html) and [CircleCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CircleCollider2D.html) interact with physics in different dimensions, box collider physics are calculated in 3D while circle collider physics are calculated in 2D. In Unity, 3D physics and 2D physics are calculated separately so collisions between 2D and 3D colliders isn't possible. You will have to replace your box collider with a [BoxCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html) or replace your circle collider with a [SphereCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SphereCollider.html). Best of luck!